# Joining ndarrays in Python where indices are floats and only approximately equal

Tags: python, join, multidimensional-array

Let's say I have two ndarrays:

```
a = [[1.1,10]
     [2.2,20]
     [3.3,30]
     [4.4,40]
     [5.5,50]]

b = [[1.5,100]
     [1.9,200]
     [2.3,250]
     [3.9,300]]
```

I want to join these two tables together so that I return:

```
c = [[1.1,10,None]
     [2.2,20,200]  #note this is 200 not 250
     [3.3,30,250]
     [4.4,40,300]
     [5.5,50,300]]
```

In other words, I want to do something like "A left join B where if the keys do not match exactly, use the key which is less than and nearest from B".

Please forgive me if I have not formatted this question correctly, it's my first question on StackOverflow, and I'm not a professional coder.  I have searched thoroughly through StackOverflow and Google though.

I have some sort of inkling that the answer could be somewhere between [merging indexed array in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2774949/merging-indexed-array-in-python)
and using a masked array.  Basically, I don't know, and please help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using [numpy.searchsorted](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.searchsorted.html):

```
import numpy as np

a = np.array([[1.1,10],
     [2.2,20],
     [3.3,30],
     [4.4,40],
     [5.5,50]])

b = np.array([[1.5,100],
     [1.9,200],
     [2.3,250],
     [3.9,300]])

idx = b[:,0].searchsorted(a[:,0], side='right')
bval = np.r_[np.nan, b[:,1]]
c = np.column_stack([a, bval[idx]])

print(c)
```

yields

```
[[   1.1   10.     nan]
 [   2.2   20.   200. ]
 [   3.3   30.   250. ]
 [   4.4   40.   300. ]
 [   5.5   50.   300. ]]
```

Note that the above calculation associates `3.3` with `250`, not `200`. If I'm understanding the problem correctly, that is the desired result, since `3.3 > 2.3`.

Comment: Great, thank you for the superfast reply!  I'll try that! And yes, you did understand the problem correctly; I have edited the question to reflect this.

Comment: This works for the above example, but is the "bval = np.r_[np.nan, b[:,1]]" line a bit of a hack?  I don't mean to be disrespectful - the answer was a great help  - but what if a[0,:] had an unknown number of values < 1.5 (the lowest value in b[0,:])?

Comment: Paraphrasing Yoda, "There is no ask, just try."