# numpy - how to outer join arrays

Tags: python, numpy

I'm trying to combine these three arrays into the one below.  Basically the equivalent of a SQL outer join (where the 'pos' field is the key/index)

```
a1 = array([('2:6506', 4.6725971801473496e-25, 0.99999999995088695),
       ('2:6601', 2.2452745388799898e-27, 0.99999999995270605),
       ('2:21801', 1.9849650921836601e-31, 0.99999999997999001),], 
      dtype=[('pos', '|S100'), ('col1', '<f8'), ('col2', '<f8')])

a2 = array([('3:6506', 4.6725971801473496e-25, 0.99999999995088695),
       ('3:6601', 2.2452745388799898e-27, 0.99999999995270605),
       ('3:21801', 1.9849650921836601e-31, 0.99999999997999001),], 
      dtype=[('pos', '|S100'), ('col1', '<f8'), ('col2', '<f8')])

a3 = array([('2:6506', 4.6725971801473496e-25, 0.99999999995088695),
       ('2:6601', 2.2452745388799898e-27, 0.99999999995270605),
       ('2:21801', 1.9849650921836601e-31, 0.99999999997999001),], 
      dtype=[('pos', '|S100'), ('col3', '<f8'), ('col4', '<f8')])
```

Desired result:

```
array([('2:6506', 4.6725971801473496e-25, 0.99999999995088695, 4.6725971801473496e-25, 0.99999999995088695),
       ('2:6601', 2.2452745388799898e-27, 0.99999999995270605, 2.2452745388799898e-27, 0.99999999995270605),
       ('2:21801', 1.9849650921836601e-31, 0.99999999997999001, 1.9849650921836601e-31, 0.99999999997999001),
       ('3:6506', 4.6725971801473496e-25, 0.99999999995088695, NaN, NaN),
       ('3:6601', 2.2452745388799898e-27, 0.99999999995270605, NaN, NaN),
       ('3:21801', 1.9849650921836601e-31, 0.99999999997999001, NaN, NaN),
        ], 
      dtype=[('pos', '|S100'), ('col1', '<f8'), ('col2', '<f8'), ('col3', '<f8'), ('col4', '<f8')])
```

I think [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2774949/merging-indexed-array-in-python?lq=1) might be on the right track, I just can't quite see how to apply it.

**Update:**

I tried running unutbu's answer but I'm getting this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "fail2.py", line 21, in <module>
    a4 = recfunctions.join_by('pos', a4, a, jointype='outer')
  File "/usr/local/msg/lib/python2.6/site-packages/numpy/lib/recfunctions.py", line 973, in join_by
    current = output[f]
  File "/usr/local/msg/lib/python2.6/site-packages/numpy/ma/core.py", line 2943, in __getitem__
    dout = ndarray.__getitem__(_data, indx)
ValueError: field named col12 not found.
```

**Update 2**

I only got this error on numpy 1.5.1.  I upgraded to 1.8.1 and it went away.

Comment: Would you post the dtypes of each of the arrays?

Comment: hmm, I just ran the code from your answer.  Doesn't that specify the dtypes?  Or you think something is altering them later on?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
import numpy as np
import numpy.lib.recfunctions as recfunctions

a1 = np.array([('2:6506', 4.6725971801473496e-25, 0.99999999995088695),
       ('2:6601', 2.2452745388799898e-27, 0.99999999995270605),
       ('2:21801', 1.9849650921836601e-31, 0.99999999997999001),], 
      dtype=[('pos', '|S100'), ('col1', '<f8'), ('col2', '<f8')])

a2 = np.array([('3:6506', 4.6725971801473496e-25, 0.99999999995088695),
       ('3:6601', 2.2452745388799898e-27, 0.99999999995270605),
       ('3:21801', 1.9849650921836601e-31, 0.99999999997999001),], 
      dtype=[('pos', '|S100'), ('col1', '<f8'), ('col2', '<f8')])

a3 = np.array([('2:6506', 4.6725971801473496e-25, 0.99999999995088695),
       ('2:6601', 2.2452745388799898e-27, 0.99999999995270605),
       ('2:21801', 1.9849650921836601e-31, 0.99999999997999001),], 
      dtype=[('pos', '|S100'), ('col3', '<f8'), ('col4', '<f8')])

result = a1
for a in (a2, a3):
    cols = list(set(result.dtype.names).intersection(a.dtype.names))
    result = recfunctions.join_by(cols, result, a, jointype='outer')
print(result)
```

yields

```
[ ('2:21801', 1.98496509218366e-31, 0.99999999997999, 1.98496509218366e-31, 0.99999999997999)
 ('2:6506', 4.67259718014735e-25, 0.999999999950887, 4.67259718014735e-25, 0.999999999950887)
 ('2:6601', 2.24527453887999e-27, 0.999999999952706, 2.24527453887999e-27, 0.999999999952706)
 ('3:21801', 1.98496509218366e-31, 0.99999999997999, --, --)
 ('3:6506', 4.67259718014735e-25, 0.999999999950887, --, --)
 ('3:6601', 2.24527453887999e-27, 0.999999999952706, --, --)]
```

---

If you are doing SQL-like joins on NumPy arrays, you might want to consider using [Pandas](http://pandas.pydata.org/). Pandas is built on NumPy and provides a richer variety of functions for manipulating data:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
a1 = np.array([('2:6506', 4.6725971801473496e-25, 0.99999999995088695),
       ('2:6601', 2.2452745388799898e-27, 0.99999999995270605),
       ('2:21801', 1.9849650921836601e-31, 0.99999999997999001),], 
      dtype=[('pos', '|S100'), ('col1', '<f8'), ('col2', '<f8')])

a2 = np.array([('3:6506', 4.6725971801473496e-25, 0.99999999995088695),
       ('3:6601', 2.2452745388799898e-27, 0.99999999995270605),
       ('3:21801', 1.9849650921836601e-31, 0.99999999997999001),], 
      dtype=[('pos', '|S100'), ('col1', '<f8'), ('col2', '<f8')])

a3 = np.array([('2:6506', 4.6725971801473496e-25, 0.99999999995088695),
       ('2:6601', 2.2452745388799898e-27, 0.99999999995270605),
       ('2:21801', 1.9849650921836601e-31, 0.99999999997999001),], 
      dtype=[('pos', '|S100'), ('col3', '<f8'), ('col4', '<f8')])

dfs = [pd.DataFrame.from_records(a) for a in (a1, a2, a3)]

result = dfs[0]
for df in dfs[1:]:
    cols = list(set(result.columns).intersection(df.columns))
    result = pd.merge(result, df, how='outer', left_on=cols, right_on=cols)

print(result)
```

yields

```
       pos          col1  col2          col3  col4
0   2:6506  4.672597e-25     1  4.672597e-25     1
1   2:6601  2.245275e-27     1  2.245275e-27     1
2  2:21801  1.984965e-31     1  1.984965e-31     1
3   3:6506  4.672597e-25     1           NaN   NaN
4   3:6601  2.245275e-27     1           NaN   NaN
5  3:21801  1.984965e-31     1           NaN   NaN

[6 rows x 5 columns]
```

Sometimes Pandas can be a bit slower than a pure NumPy solution. But that is often because Pandas provides a more robust solution which correctly handles corner cases such as NaNs or duplicate index values -- things that an ad hoc NumPy solution may not be addressing.

Also note that Pandas DataFrames have a `.values` attribute which returns a NumPy array of the underlying data, and a `.to_records` method which returns a structured array. And as you can see above, there is a `Dataframe.from_records` constructor which converts structured arrays to DataFrames. So you can move between DataFrames and NumPy arrays quite easily if you really need to.

So I don't think there is any real speed disadvantage to using Pandas, and the convenience it provides should allow you to do more data analysis, much more easily.

Comment: That seems like it should work.  But I'm getting an error.  I updated the question with the error since I can't format it here.

Comment: Good idea about pandas.  Would there be a speed penalty?  Is there something fundamentally wrong with the original numpy approach?

Comment: No, there is nothing fundamentally wrong with using NumPy structured arrays, but I must say I find working with Pandas DataFrames a pleasure while doing certain things with NumPy structured arrays seems more like a fight. For example, there is no easy way to sub-select columns.

Comment: Sorry, I don't know why you are seeing an error when running the code I posted. :(  I'm using Python2.7, not 2.6, but I couldn't locate any relevant bug report, so the version difference may not be the problem.

Comment: Could it be an issue with the version?  I'm on numpy 1.5.1.

Comment: I happen to be running NumPy 1.8.1, but I have no reason to believe this should not work with 1.5.1 also.

Comment: I upgraded to 1.8.1 and it works!  Thanks for your help.

Comment: Actually I just noticed, for example in your pandas output, col1_x and col1_y should be the same column.  (and same thing for col2_x and col2_y).  Any ideas?

Comment: It sounds like the join key is not just pos, but also any shared column names. I've modified the code above to show how this could be done.